# How do I get a list of all loaded Types in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I need to retrieve all enums that were loaded from a given set of Assemblies.

Comment: What does "that were loaded" mean?  Can you give an example of a type that was not loaded vs a type that is loaded?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
List<Type> list = new List<Type>();
foreach (Assembly ass in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
{
    foreach (Type t in ass.GetExportedTypes())
    {
        if (t.IsEnum)
        {
            list.Add(t);
        }
    }
}
```

That should do, for all assemblies loaded by the current Appdomain, to get just from defined assemblies, just adjust ;-)

Comment: Funny part (phonetically) : "just adjust" :)

Comment: this code will fail if there exist an dynamic assembly in loaded ones

Answer (score 8):

Here is a more functional solution:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
    .SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes())
    .Where(t => t.IsEnum)
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have the list of `Assembly` objects you want to check:

```
IEnumerable<Assembly> assemblies; // assign the assemblies you want to check here

foreach (Assembly a in assemblies) {
    foreach (Type t in assembly.GetTypes()) {
        if (t.IsEnum) {
            // found an enum! Do whatever...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use `Assembly.GetTypes()` to get all the types for the assembly. For each type, you can use `Type.IsEnum` property to see if it's an enum.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use LINQ to return a list of all enum types from a list of assemblies.

```
IEnumerable<Assembly> assemblies;
// give assemblies some value
var enums = from assembly in assemblies let types = assembly.GetTypes() from type in types where type.IsEnum select type;
```

`enums` will be of type IEnumerable.