# get object of class based on generic interface

Tags: c#, generics, compare

I have the following implementation for comparing two objects.

```
public interface IEqualityDefinition<T>
{
    bool Compare(object source, T target);
}

public class BlockEqualityDefinition : IEqualityDefinition<Block>
{
    public bool Compare(object source, Block target)
    {
        // compare stuff..
        return false;
    }
}
```

I used an generic interface to specify for which class i want to compare.
Next i have the following method:

```
public bool Compare(object source, object target)
{
    // Here i want something else
    IEqualityDefinition definition = new BlockEqualityDefinition();

    return definition.Compare(source, target);
}
```

In this method i want to instantiate an class based on the 'target' parameter. For example, when the 'target' parameter contains an 'Block' object, i want that the right EqualityDefinition class is called to do the comparisation stuff for me.

What's the best way to do this? I can't figure it out right now.
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Two options from the top of my head:

- Create a map in code where you store your implementations

  ```
  Dictionary<Type, IEqualityDefinition>
  ```

  Add your implementations to it

  ```
  EqualityMap.Add(typeof(Block), new BlockEqualityDefinition)
  ```

  And query it by the type you add.

  ```
  EqualityMap[target.GetType()]
  ```
- Or have an interface for scanning all loaded assemblies for types imlementing the wanted. Like in [How do i get a list of all loaded types in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1914058/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-all-loaded-types-in-c)

  To not always scan all loaded types, cache these in a Map like in the first option.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into factories. The factory pattern enables you exactly that.

(Actually not so good) Example from [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/factory):

```
class Factory
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Decides which class to instantiate.
    /// </summary>
    public static Position Get(int id)
    {
        switch (id)
        {
        case 0:
            return new Manager();
        case 1:
        case 2:
            return new Clerk();
        case 3:
        default:
            return new Programmer();
        }
    }
}
```

But in your case (actually in most cases) i would say you should use an enum instead of an int - its better to refactor, to understand and to read:

```
public enum EqualityDefinitions
{
    Block // or BlockEquality 
    // and more
}
```

and then you can use it like this:

```
class EqualityDefinitionFactory
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Decides which class to instantiate.
    /// </summary>
    public static IEqualityDefinition Get(EqualityDefinitions definition)
    {
        switch (definition)
        {
            case EqualityDefinitions.BlockEquality:
                return new BlockEqualityDefinition();
            default:
                throw new NotImplementedException("Unknown type");
        }
    }
}
```